# Detect time range duplication in Excel worksheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a schedule table in excel that contain :

```
Task - Begine Time - End Time
A    - 10:00       - 10:30
B    - 10:35       - 11:44
C    - 10:20       - 11:15
D    - 12:00       - 13:12
```

I want to create a formula that detect if a task is scheduled in another task time ;
Eg : Task C begin when Task B is running.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Best way to solve this would be to sort the tasks into order of start time then by finish time, then you can just check for each start time whetehr the finish time in the row above is later than the start time for the current row, then you have an overlap.

```
 (Col)(A)    (B)           (C)      
(Row) Task - Begin  Time - End Time - Okay?
(1)   A    - 10:00       - 10:30    - 
(2)   C    - 10:20       - 11:15    - =B2 > C1
(3)   B    - 10:35       - 11:44    - =B3 > C2
(4)   D    - 12:00       - 13:12    - =B4 > C3
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I am not sure whether you want SQL, VBA or a formula solution so offer a chart for consideration:

[image: SO26115451 example]

Comment: thanks, i used a gantt chart before, but my table contain 10000 line

Answer (score 0):

Add another column to your table to check whether your begin times for each task occur before the end of any other tasks AND after the start of those tasks:

```
Task    Start   End Clash?
a   10:00   10:30   0
b   10:35   11:44   1
c   10:20   11:15   1
d   12:00   13:12   0
```

The formula I have put in the 'Clash?' column is as follows:

=SUMPRODUCT(N([Start]<[@Start]),N([End]>[@Start]))

Hope that helps!

Comment: This would still work but you would end up with a very large table (would be at the row limit for Excel 2010). You could add a column to your table which checks each Task begin time to see whether it occurs before the end of another task but after the start of that task - I'll be back with a formula